# How to create a view using data from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have two tables

**ITEM**

- id (int),
- model (varchar),
- weight (float),
- fk_type (int)

**TYPE**

- id (int),
- name (varchar)

And I want to create a view with

- TypeName (for every type name) --> varchar
- NumberOfItems (total number of ITEMS for TypeName) ---> int
- NumberOfModels (total number of MODELS for TypeName) ---> int
- TotWeight (again sum of all the ITEMS weight per TypeName) --->float

For example: I have three pencils, two of them have the same model, and one rubber. I'm expecting to get something like this.

| TypeName | NumberOfItems | NumberOfModels | TotWeight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pencil | 3 | 2 | 50 |
| rubber | 1 | 1 | 25 |

I tried something like this but I can't get my head around it

```
SELECT 
    Type.Name,
    (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Item.fk_Type) FROM Item GROUP BY  Item.fk_Type) NumberOfItems, 
    (SELECT COUNT(Item.Model) FROM Item,Type WHERE Item.fk_Type = Type.Id)NumberOfModels ,
    (SELECT SUM(Item.Weight) FROM Item,Type WHERE Item.fk_Type = Type.Id)TotWeight
FROM 
    Item, Type 
GROUP BY 
    Type.Name
```

Can someone help?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically an aggregation query with a `join`:

```
select t.name, count(i.id) as num_items,
       count(distinct i.model) as num_models,
       sum(i.weight) as total_weight
from type t left join
     item i
     on i.fk_type = t.id
group by t.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Joins

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

try to look correct table names.